# What does .split() change in this instance of code

Tags: python, python-3.x

While I was practising List Comprehensions I stumbled onto this interesting situation.
I was trying to print words which had less than four letters from the string assigned to the variable `string_1`.
I thought I had finished this simple code and proceeded to run it. It was then that I realized that the output hadn't changed, the condition of < 4 had altered nothing at all. I looked for some solutions and found one. My problem now is understanding why the first code didn't work but the second one did, to me they seem to do basically the same thing.

**Code 1 (*Failed*):**

```
string_1 = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog"
words = [word for word in string_1 if len(word) < 4]
print("".join(words))
```

**Code 1 (*output*):** The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog

**Code 2 (*Worked*):**

```
string_1 = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog"
words = [word for word in string_1.split() if len(word) < 4]
print(" ".join(words))
```

**Code 2 (*output*):** The fox the dog

Comment: Code 1 is effectively splitting the string into individual characters.  All of the characters have a length less than 4, of course.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Check out the [tour] and [ask].

Comment: @jasonharper so by doing .split() the string is converted into a list which contains word by word?

Comment: What makes you think that the two pieces of code "seem to do basically the same thing"?

Comment: @blhsing I thought they both did the same thing...grabbing each word from the string and checking the length of it, but then I realized with help from the answers here, that the first one iterates all the characters one by one, on the other hand, the second one iterates them word by word.

Comment: @Marstjugo Yeah, but my point is that I don't see why you would ever want to assume that the two pieces of code would do the same thing when they are literally different. The call to the `split` method is apparently there to do *something*, and you just need to look up the reference to find out what that *something* is.

Comment: @BorisLipschitz thank you ;(

Comment: @blhsing I was suspecting something like this but I wanted to make sure ;(

Comment: I’m voting to close this as I can’t really see it benefiting or being relevant to anyone in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By removing the `if` from **Code 1** we can see the problem:

```
string_1 = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog"
words = [word for word in string_1]
print(words)
```

Outputs:

```
['T', 'h', 'e', ' ', 'q', 'u', 'i', 'c', 'k', ' ', 'b', 'r', 'o', 'w', 'n', ' ', 'f', 'o', 'x', ' ', 'j', 'u', 'm', 'p', 's', ' ', 'o', 'v', 'e', 'r', ' ', 't', 'h', 'e', ' ', 'l', 'a', 'z', 'y', ' ', 'd', 'o', 'g']
```

By iterating over a string, you get character-by-character. Of course `len('T')` (or any other character) is always smaller than 4, so you get an empty list.

When you split it, you get word by word.

Answer (score 1):

First one iterates character by character. The second one iterates word by word.

Example, to make it simple to understand on an actual runnable code:

```
print([x for x in "a b c"])
print([x for x in "a b c".split()])
```

Output:

```
['a', ' ', 'b', ' ', 'c']
['a', 'b', 'c']
```

Answer (score -1):

at first case your code split string_1 letter by letter but in second example the split() method splits the string when  face to the space and then add it to the list and check the length and if the length is lesser than 4 letter then join the words .
you can see this code:`

```
string_1 = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog"
words = [word for word in string_1 if len(word) < 4]
print(words)
print("".join(words))



['T', 'h', 'e', ' ', 'q', 'u', 'i', 'c', 'k', ' ', 'b', 'r', 'o', 'w', 'n', ' ', 'f', 
'o', 'x', ' ', 'j', 'u', 'm', 'p', 's', ' ', 'o', 'v', 'e', 'r', ' ', 't', 'h', 'e', ' 
', 'l', 'a', 'z', 'y', ' ', 'd', 'o', 'g']
```

Answer (score -1):

```
string = "The quick brown fox"

print(list(string))
```

Output:
[image]